# Java, ConcurrentLinkedDeque vs ConcurrentLinkedQueue - the difference?

Tags: java, collections

Api links for **ConcurrentLinkedDeque** and **ConcurrentLinkedQueue**:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

What is the difference between the two?

The first one, DeQueue has a lot more methods, but what is the **fundamental** difference between the two?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both collections are thread-safe. The difference is that a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` implements a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), which supports addition and removal of elements at both ends (e.g. `addFirst` and `addLast`), whereas `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` implements a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) which allows insertion at one end called the tail of the queue and removal at the other end, called the head of the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Dequeue allows insertions & deletions from both the ends of the queue that is why there are many methods.

While queue does not.